# How to handle FileSystemException in dart when watching a directory

Tags: dart

I have written a simple command line tool in dart that watches changes in a directory if a directory does not exits I get FileSystemsException.

I have tried to handle it using try and catch clause. When the exception occurs the code in catch clause is not executed

```
try {
watcher.events.listen((event) {
  if (event.type == ChangeType.ADD) {
    print("THE FILE WAS ADDED");
    print(event.path);
} else if (event.type == ChangeType.MODIFY) {
    print("THE FILE WAS MODIFIED");
    print(event.path);
} else {
    print("THE FILE WAS REMOVED");
    print(event.path);
}
});
} on FileSystemException {
  print("Exception Occurs");
}
```

I expect the console to print "Exception Occurs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The exception is happening outside this block (maybe where the watcher is constructed?)
2. The exception is an unhandled async exception. This might be coming from either the Stream or it might be getting fired from some other Future, like perhaps the `ready` Future.

You can add handlers for the async exceptions like this:

```
try {
  // If this is in an `async` method, use `await` within the try block
  await watcher.ready;
  // Otherwise add a error handler on the Future
  watcher.ready.catchError((e) {
    print('Exception in the ready Future');
  });

  watcher.events.listen((event) {
    ...
  }, onError: (e) {
    print('Exception in the Stream');
  });
} on FileSystemException {
  print("Exception Occurs");
}
```

My guess would be it's an error surfaced through the `ready` Future.